# Can I transfer an app that is installed from Windows Phones 8.1 to PC?

Tags: automated-tests, windows-phone-8.1, app.xaml

I have an app that is installed in Windows Phone 8.1 from PC by Visual Studio. Can I get it again to PC from my Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that with the publically available tools.

Only isolated storage is accessible from the PC.